# Integer solutions of a two-variable linear equation.

Tags: number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

The question is:

Find all pairs of integers $(x, y)$ such that $61x+18y = 0$.

By solving for $x$, we have $x = (-18/61) \cdot y$, therefore $x$ is an integer if-f $y$ is a multiple of $61$.

Similarly, by solving for $y$, we have $y = (-61/18) \cdot x$, therefore $y$ is an integer if-f $x$ is a multiple of $18$.

Therefore, the solutions are of the form $(x,y)$, where $x = 18k$ and $y =(-61/18)\cdot x$, for all integer $k$.

Is this right? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks right to me.

Comment: Thank you, my main problem was if my method indeed gave us ALL pairs of solutions.

Comment: And if x is, indeed, an integer IF AND ONLY IF y is a multiple of 61, or there are other cases where x is a integer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do better. Your characterization is problematic because you cannot know in advance, before arithmetic, which $k$ will fit.

Consider that $\gcd(18,61) = 1$, which means that starting with $k=0 \iff x=y=0$, you must add multiples of $18 \cdot 61$ to make things work. The idea would be to write a characterization to work for *every* $k$...

Comment: I think my limited experience prevents me from fully understanding your answer. What concerns me is that, if we write the solutions as x = 18*k and y =(-61/18)*x, then this seems to me that this works for every integer k: plug in every integer k to the above solutions and you get all possible pairs. Once again, excuse me for not understanding your argument, I would be very grateful if you could explain it in simpler terms.

Comment: @JBuck not quite. For example, if $k=1$ then $x=18$ and $y=-61/18$ so $y$ is **not** an integer. If you are looking for real solutions, this would work. But if $x,y$ must be integers, you need to know which $k$ would "work" in your formulation. That's inconvenient. I am suggesting how to reformulate so it would work for **every** $k$